# How to paste from clipboard into KiTTY SSH terminal window?

Tags: windows, ssh, putty, clipboard

I use KiTTY (a PuTTY derivative) to access SSH servers from a Windows PC. But I can't find how to paste text from Windows clipboard into KiTTY SSH console (neither Ctrl+V, nor Ctrl+Shift+V seem to work, and there does not seem to be Copy/Paste commands in the window's context menu). Maybe you know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right-click somewhere inside the terminal window.

I pasted "administrator" by right-clicking somewhere inside the terminal window. (The black area)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I've seen this, but thought it only pastes what is selected inside the KiTTY window itself.

Comment: Heads-up: I **have to press Shift** for the right-click to work. (Kitty version: 0.76)

Answer (score 8):

Copy and paste works similarly to the X Window System.
You use the left mouse button to select text in the PuTTY window. 
The act of selection automatically copies the text to the clipboard: there is no need to press Ctrl-Ins or Ctrl-C or anything else. 
The only thing you need to do, to copy text to the clipboard, is to select it.
To paste the clipboard contents into a PuTTY window, by default you click the right mouse button. 
You can also paste by pressing Shift-Ins.

see: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/faq.html

Answer (score 2):

To paste into a terminal window press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>.